# SameSite=Lax blocks cookies from the same domain, sayng it's different domain

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, samesite

I'm having a page, that redirects to an external URL, where a customer is adding their data and then is returned back to my site. However when the customer is returned the session cookie is blocked by the browser, because "the request comes from a different site". This happens in FireFox (with SameSite=Lax) 100% of the times and "whenever it wants" in Chrome. I don't understand why does this happen, how does it see the site is different and what really the site is (there is no info in the Dev tools).

This blocking logouts the customer and I need them to be logged in.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I did a workaround. I'm posting it here in case somebody has the same issue and the fix will work for them. When the user is redirected to the other side I'm sending a session id in the return URL. The if the user is returned and is not logged in I add the cookie with that id and refresh the page, this way the user is returned logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is: when user came back to your site, he no longer needs to login. So in your back-end, just set the cookie's flag to `Samesite = None; Secure`. This will make the browser to send cookies regardless of where he came from ( the external domain ).

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to send the cookie to the external domain. That is a security issue. I want to know why it is recognized as a different domain, since the return URL is in the same domain as the one that set the cookie.

Comment: Yeah you are right, its will be a security issue. Btw you can try to open a new window instead of redirect. So a customer did adding their data and when it has done, the window closed. This way you don't have to deal with your site's cookies anymore.